# Wicket FilterToolbar refresh DataTable

Tags: datatable, wicket

I use a `DefaultDataTable` with a `FilterToolbar`. Beside that I add my own toolbar on the bottom which calculates a sum on the given dataprovider.

When I filter the datatable by entering text into the textfield, the data itself gets updated correctly, but it doesn't refresh my toolbar.

How can I force it to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I am not too familiar with the `FilterToolbar` API. But in general you can make a component refresh by adding it to an `AjaxRequestTarget`. Such targets are provided for the java code whenever the user triggers some ajax request - which is the case when the content of the textfield changes.

For example if you would have a common textfield (not tied to a FilterToolbar) you could simply add an `AjaxEventBehavior` to it, this class has an `onEvent` method which is called whenever the textfield's content changes and provides you with a working instance of AjaxRequestTarget.
Then simply call `target.add(myToolbar);` - this triggers a refresh of the added component.

Without any code example of yours you have to see for yourself whether you can hook in any event behavior or maybe just use an existing method that gets called on updates and gets provided an AjaxRequestTarget.